# Is it possible to get translate3d working smoothly in the Android browser?

Tags: html, css, cordova

I'm working on an HTML5 interactive using phonegap and one of my pages involves using pinch-zoom functionality on an image. I've managed to get this working perfectly using the [iScroll][1] plugin but the zooming functionality is unacceptably slow. On the iPad however, everything runs incredibly smoothly.

I did read that the CSS 3 'translate3d' attribute can be used to force hardware acceleration (and this seems to be working on the iPad) but doesn't seem to have any effect on Android. From what I've read it *seems* that hardware acceleration isn't yet supported on Android browsers but I'm basically asking whether this is false and it is indeed possible *or* if there are any effective workarounds?[1]: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Answer (score 0):

depending of android version, see canius : http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Comment: I have version 4.1 which according to that, means I should have hardware acceleration. However the pinch/zoom is nowhere near as smooth as the ipad..

Comment: iPad have "good" CPU/GPU, their is some android device, each have differents CPU/GPU ; what is you device model ? you can also test on Chrome for Android (better in some points as default android browser)